# Memory leak by local pointer inside C++ constructor body

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

Hi have a code very similar to this

```
// Constructor
Foo() {
int * ptr = new int[100];
/* More Stuff */
}
```

This is resulting in Memory Leak, is there any way of deleting `ptr` without making it a member variable ?

Comment: You'll have to store the pointer *somewhere* if you want to delete it later. You could also store it in a global variable, add it to some container, or similar.

Comment: Why do you need to use `new` here? If the size is known at compile-time you could use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead (or plain C-style arrays). Otherwise [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: I assume that you don't need the pointer after the constructor anymore? Then why don't delete it right there? If it really is a `int[100]` array, you also could use `std::vector` which will handle the dynamic memory allocation and deallocation. Using `new` should be avoided

Comment: It's really not clear what part of basic memory management you're struggling with, and in what way. You should expand your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you do it. When you don't need `ptr` anymore, delete it:

```
delete[] ptr;
```

Make sure to look up the difference between `delete` and `delete[]`. [Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) is a reference.

Having said that, the Right Thing<sup>TM</sup> is to use [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). Or if you simply need a dynamically sized array, use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).